# Find my iPhone shows phone offline, when it's in my hand, right by the other one...NOT off

Tags: iphone

All the answers to the find my iPhone being offline do not apply to me. The "offline" phone is in my hand. All the settings are on, just like the phone in my other hand.Yet, it shows the first one to be offline. I'm right by the hotspot, so it has internet. Should be no problem. It also does not show to be offline when I look on the iPad that pairs with that phone or from the desktop.

I also can't get the other iPhone or iPad to show up on that same phone when I set them all up. Any help there?
thanks!

Comment: Toggle Find My iPhone off and on under iCloud in Settings app and see if the device becomes online.

Comment: "All the other answers ..." is a vague statement and essentially meaningless, because we don't know what you've tried to fix this. First thing I'd to do is log out from iCloud on this device and login back in. Second - do a hard restart (hold down power and home button simultaneously until it restarts.) Third, disconnect and reconnect from Wi-Fi, not just a toggle off/on, but click the (I) next to the network name and select Forget this network, then re-connect with credentials. (As @NimeshNeema indicates above, try toggling Find My iPhone off/on, too.)

Comment: How's a hard restart different from a soft restart in this case?